# Achieve tooltip like this in VB.net?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms, tooltip

I found this tooltip that pops up in MS Word 2010 when someone enters a copy count above 32767, I would like to know how (and if) it is possible to implement a tooltip such as this within a VB.net windows form application.

[image: tooltip screenshot MSWord 2010]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The built-in ToolTip component creates a tooltip that looks pretty close.  Set its IsBalloon property to True.  Getting it *exactly* like Word is not practical, the component doesn't provide any way to override the TOOLINFO.uFlags value so you could specify TTF_CENTERTIP..

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I tried the Balloon, but it was unpredictable as to which way it was orientated. However, the following code might get you started... I assume it's not bullet proof so you might need to add some more code.

I used a textbox and a tooltip from the tools menu:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles      TextBox1.TextChanged

If Val(TextBox1.Text) > 100 Then
        ToolTip1.Active = True
        ToolTip1.Show("Value is to Large", sender, New Drawing.Point(0, sender.Height - 50))
    Else
        ToolTip1.Active = False
    End If

End Sub
```

I really like this idea... Thanks!